# Handle idle sleep from audio virtual driver - Mac OSX

Tags: osx-lion, core-audio, audio-streaming, kernel-extension

We have an virtual audio device driver similar to Sound flower. This virtual device will be listed in sound system preferences.  Whenever our device gets selected in system preferences, it prevents idle sleep. If we switch the selection to default output device, everything works as expected.

If we execute 'pmset -g assertions' command in Terminal, it gives below output

```
Assertion status system-wide:  
   ChargeInhibit                           0
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep             0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep              1
   NoRealPowerSources_debug                0
   CPUBoundAssertion                       0
   EnableIdleSleep                         1
   PreventSystemSleep                      0
   DisableInflow                           0
   DisableLowPowerBatteryWarnings          0
   ExternalMedia                           0

Listed by owning process:

   pid 115: [0x0000012c00000073] PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: MY_DRIVER_IDENTIFER.noidlesleep"
```

Could any one suggest me some pointers to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this governed by the flag `kIOPMPreventIdleSleep`, which resides in the `capabilityFlags` field of the [`IOPMPowerState` struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/IOPMpowerState_h/index.html).

To participate in power management decisions, you'll need to add your device driver to the power management plane, typically in your overridden `IOService::start(provider)` method:

```
PMinit();
provider->joinPMtree(this);
registerPowerDriver(this, powerStates, numPowerStates);
```

where `powerStates` and `numPowerStates` specifies an array of power states you want your device to be able to be in. You'll probably not want more than 2 for a virtual device, and maybe you even only need one. I suspect a superclass of your class is setting states that are inhibiting sleep. Once you've registered for power management, your driver will be expected to handle the power management methods such as `IOService::setPowerState()`.

Depending on how you want your device to behave, you might want to create 2 power states, one "live" when playing back or capturing sound (and inhibiting sleep) and the other "idle" when the device isn't doing anything, and allowing sleep.

The power management topic is a bit too big to cover entirely in a StackOverflow answer, so I suggest you read the docs on the stuff I've mentioned above and try clearing the relevant flag in your power state(s).

Hope that helps.